# check whether csv form or not

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a string whether is is csv or not.

here's mine .

```
/^(\w*)?(,\s)?(\w*)?/ig
```

It matches when I tried one line like

```
abcd, abcd
```

but when I tried other language like

```
ㄱㄴㄷㄹ, ㄱㄷㄹㄷ
```

or

```
ナムウィキ, ナムウィキ
```

it doesn't match. Is there are way to solve this difficulty?

Comment: Try `^[^,]+(?:,[^,]*)*$`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/ezd3oe/1

Comment: @revo it works perfectly!